# LLDP chassis ID origin

Tags: networking, snmp, topology

I am learning about LLDP protocol and have stumbled across terms `chassis ID` and `port ID`. If I understand correctly they can be used by network management systems to determine connections between various devices in the network.

**Question**: 
Where does the system get its `chassis ID` from?

AFAIK there is no way to get a per-device unique identifier (for every possible device model). Also, on an Extreme switch I queried for SNMP OID `1.0.8802.1.1.2.1.3.2` (LLDP_LOC_CHASSIS_ID) I got back 6 bytes which seems a bit short for a worldwide device identifier. Am I missing something? Is chassis ID just some random number and implementators figured that the likelihood of collision was too low to worry about?

**Bonus question 1**:
At what point is LLDP `chassis ID` initialized? My guess is that it shouldn't change even if LLDP is disabled and then re-enabled. If this is so, is it possible to get it somehow even if LLDP is disabled?

**Bonus question 2**:
Does LLDP `chassis ID` change if you use another LLDP daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *Chassis ID* is not designed to be a vendor unique identifier, and the value of LLDP's *Chassis Type* relates to what the *Chassis ID* actually is, I'd wager the 6 bytes you see are the MAC address of the switch.

Comment: Thanks! I found mention of *chassis type* in LLDP specification and it would help a lot if I could get it via SNMP - is there an OID I can query to get chassis type or is it just part of ethernet packets?